# Why are wolves associated with regeneration?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins, noblesse

In the manga *Noblesse*, wolves' main attribute is their regenerative abilities (like Wolverine). Same with Ban (fox) from *Nanatsu no Taizai*.

Are there some explanation on why fox or wolves are associated with healing or regeneration abilities?

Comment: a note about tags: usually tags are used for large topics or something that could have people knowledgeable about it in the context of the site's topic. There aren't any "regeneration" specialists on the site. The closest thing to that would be biologists on [Biology.SE]. And Wolverine anime has nothing to do with this question coz it's a whole other creature.

Comment: Foxes, wolves, and wolverines are three entirely different kinds of animals.

Answer (score 2):

In Ban's case, the fox is linked to his sin of greed, because he drank the fountain of youth. But I guess in Japan, their ability to heal comes from the Fox Demons called Kitsune which have a variety of powers.

And I would guess the wolves' healing comes from the Werewolves Tales where they would heal any wound immediately if it wasn't inflicted with a silver weapon.